# Переход по ссылке при помощи VBS

Tags: vbscript

Хочу создать скрипит VBS, чтобы сначала выводилось окно "перейти по ссылке?" и внизу кнопка да и кнопка нет. При нажатии Да открывается сайт, допустим [www.site.com](http://www.site.com). при нажатии "нет" и при закрытии окна ничего не происходит.

Относительно сообщения я имею некоторые догадки, а с сайтом - хз. Предполагаю использовать браузер MS Edge

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Dim wsh

If MsgBox("Открыть сайт rbc.ru?", 4, "Открытие сайта") = 6 Then 
    SET wsh = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    wsh.run "https://rbc.ru"
End if
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]